# Find an integer $x$ such that $2^x \equiv 3\pmod{p}$ given prime $p$

Tags: prime-numbers, modular-arithmetic

So I am studying for finals and I am not able to solve the problem:

Let $p=3\times2^{11484018}−1$ be a prime with 3457035 digits. Find a positive integer $x$ so that 
$$2^x \equiv 3 \pmod p$$

Any guidance or tips would be great. I assumed it dealt with Fermat's Little theorem.

Comment: Please be concise in question posing.  There's no need to mention you're studying for finals.  There's no need to say you're not able to solve the problem (obviously).    Including code you've tried could help potential solvers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You know that

```
Mod[a^(p - 1), p] == 1
```

In particular

```
Mod[2^(p - 1), p] == 1
```

And multiplying by 3

```
Mod[3 2^(p - 1), p] == 3
```

Now we divide and multiply by 2

```
Mod[3 2 2^(p - 2), p] == 3
```

Rearranging:

```
Mod[2 (3 2^(p - 2)), p] == 3
```

So

```
x === (3 2^(p - 2))
```